# Define date type in Magento widget

Tags: magento

I want to write a widget which allow input 2 date. I would like know type of date in magento.
Example this is text type in etc/widget.xml:

```
<parameters>
       <limit_count>
            <label>Limit Count</label>
            <description>The numbers of product will be show</description>
            <visible>1</visible>
            <required>1</required>
            <type>**text**</type>
        </limit_count>
    </parameters>
```

I want to change text type to datetime type. Is there way to resovle my problem. Thanks

Comment: Types are limited to 'text', 'select', 'multiselect' and 'label'. See :http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-magento-widget-part-2

Comment: @Lishamatish Thanks for reply. How to define other data type such as: date, colorbox, drag & drop object , vv